# Effective way to implement 'if else' condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three database boolean columns `google`, `yahoo`, `bing`. I need to print them on html.erb page like this.

- `"google + yahoo + bing"` if all three are `true`.
- `"google + yahoo"` if only `google` and `yahoo` are `true`.
- `"google"` if only `google` is `true`.

Is there an effective way to implement this? If I do it in a traditional way, then `if .. else` conditions will be large.

Comment: What happens with other combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution (assuming your object is @m)

```
<%= "#{'google' if @m.google}" + 
    "#{' + '    if @m.google && @m.yahoo}" +
    "#{'yahoo'  if @m.yahoo}" +
    "#{' + '    if (@m.yahoo && @m.bing) || (@m.google && @m.bing)}" +
    "#{'bing'   if @m.bing}"
%>
```

Comment: But it's bad design. You don't want to have such logic in your templates. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/45932189/299774 approach, preferably put this method in helper or model's decorator.

Comment: While this approach may work for three attributes, it won't scale well.

Comment: indeed the approach by @unkmas would be better

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
def result
   %w[google yahoo bing].keep_if {|m| obj.public_send(m) }.join(' + ')
end
```

Comment: If `obj` is a Rails model, you could use `obj[m]` instead of `public_send` to access the attribute.

Comment: @Stefan i think it's better to use `public_send`, because model can contain some additional logic on getter.

Answer (score 2):

You can push the values into the array and join them, like this

```
search_engines = []
search_engines << 'google' if google
search_engines << 'yahoo'  if yahoo
search_engines << 'bing'   if bing

search_engines.join(' + ')
```

Its not recommended to put this directly inside the view, there are two options

1. Pull this code into the respective view_helper method and call that method in the view.
2. If this piece of code is not only used in view but also has business logic you can pull this code into a model and then you can call this method using the instance.
   Eg: obj.search_engines.join(' + ') (assuming that the name of the method is search_engines and you are returning only an array from the method)

Answer (score 1):

use helper method,

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_platform(obj)
    straray = []
    strarray << 'google' if obj.google 
    strarray << ' + '    if obj.google && obj.yahoo
    strarray << 'yahoo'  if obj.yahoo
    strarray << ' + '    if obj.yahoo && obj.bing) || (obj.google && obj.bing)
    strarray << 'bing'   if obj.bing

    strarray.join
  end
end
```

call this `= get_platform(obj)`

Comment: I'd agree that a helper is better than jamming all that logic into the view but why not leave the `' + '` stuff until the final `join`? And I think you have a stray `+` in the `if obj.yahoo +` part.

Comment: I think this can be refactored though. I did not get into logic much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `my_object` object,

```
%i(google yahoo bing).map do |engine|
  engine if my_object[engine]
end.compact.join(' + ')
```

This solution is easily extensible to any number of engines.

Comment: Why `map` and `compact` when we have [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)?

Answer (score -3):

```
(google && yahoo)? ? "google + yahoo" : ((google && yahoo && bing))? ? "google + yahoo + bing" : (google)? ? "google" : "none"
```

use ternary operator but it is little bit complex

Comment: ternary operator will be way too long. keeping in mind only "yahoo" or only "bing" can also be true.